# Optimise Rails Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, serialization

I have performance problems with a Rails 6 API.

```
class OfferSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
attributes :id, :ident, :label, :slug, :pagetitle, :description
has_many :users, serializer: UserSerializer
```

The User has many attributes which I do not need rendering the offers. Is there a way to constraint the user attributes here? 
I need all user attributes on rendering the users, so I cannot reduce it in the user Serializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is the exact performance issue you're having and whether the culprit is UserSerializer serializing all fields, but you should be able to do something like this if you need to pick attributes that should be serialized:

```
class OfferSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  attributes :id, :ident, :label, :slug, :pagetitle, :description
  has_many :users, serializer: UserSerializer, attributes: [:id, :name, :whatever]

  # ...
end
```

You can also create a custom serializer for that purpose only, e.g. LightweightUserSerializer:

```
class LightweightUserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name # ...
end
```

And then use it:

```
class OfferSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  attributes :id, :ident, :label, :slug, :pagetitle, :description
  has_many :users, serializer: LightweightUserSerializer

  # ...
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That was not clear to me that I could just add another Serializer. The first idea did not work for me. When you have a lot of user attributes with lots of text..Takes some time to pass it to the frontend.. Thanks..very helpful